# Webview Offline Caching: ERR_CACHE_MISS

Tags: android, caching, webview, offline

I have an app (only WebView) for opening a website. I want to make the app for offline-using. So I used  getSettings().setAppCachePath() and getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ONLY).

When I open a page connected to Wifi it works. But open the same page again it doesn't work and it's only shown: ERR_CACHE_MISS

What is wrong?

Here is my code:

```
public WebView mWebView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tischtennis);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient());

    // Enable Javascript
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    // Cookies
    CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);

    // CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(true);

    // Caching
    mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1024*1024*10);
    String cacheDir = getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath();
    mWebView.getSettings().setAppCachePath(cacheDir);
    mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);

    // Offline Support
    if ( isNetworkAvailable() ) {
        mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
    } else {
        mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ONLY);
    }

    mWebView.loadUrl("www........");
}

private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(getApplicationContext().CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

And my Manifest-permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```